# Making a text box replace a \vspace

Tags: spacing, boxes

I have an `enumerate` list that has it's items separated by a `\vspace {1 in}`.

Each `\item` is a question that needs to be answered within that space, and, I want to create a "possible answers sheet", where I type in some possible answers for the questions. I would like the answer sheet to keep the same page layout and page number as the original file so I need my answers to fit inside a " box" with 1 inch height. I will also need those boxes to allow me to change font size, color and also allow me to use math mode.

```
\item This is question 1.

\vspace{1 in}
%I need to replace this with the "answer box"

 \item This is question 2. So how much is $2+2$

\vspace{1 in}
%I need this box to allow me to type $2+2=4$

*continues on*
```

Comment: There are a number of packages (exam.cls for example) which do this sort of thing.  Personally, I don't use them (see http://www.elfsoft2000.com/worksheets/index.htm).

Comment: I was hoping to do it without those exam-like packages, actually.

Comment: using the vspace mid document is misusing the list really. The whole point of list structures is that you specify in advance teh vertical and horizontal space requirements. If you used a list with `\itemsep` being set to 1in items would be separated by 1in no need for vspace on every item.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just used 1in as an example, on my usual files I have different spacings for different items. Thank you for the alert, though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another iteration of the same sort of thing.  You could add some frills, but here it goes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter

\newcounter{ae@problem@cnt}
\newcommand\problem{\stepcounter{ae@problem@cnt}\textbf{\arabic{ae@problem@cnt})}\hspace*{0.5em}}

\newsavebox\ae@question@box
\newsavebox\ae@answer@box
\newif\if@showanswer@
%% a command to format the boxes for question and answer
%% #1=control sequence for box                          
%% #2=width of box                                      
%% #3=content of box                                    
\long\def\ae@save@mp#1#2#3{%%
  \begin{lrbox}{#1}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{#2}
      #3
    \end{minipage}
  \end{lrbox}}

%% a command to trigger when aswers will appear
\newcommand\showanswers{\@showanswer@true}
%% Using two boxes is probably overkill
%% only one for the answer would suffice.
%% #1=height of answer space
%% #2=content of question
%% #3=content of answer
\newcommand\question[3][1in]{%%
  \ae@save@mp\ae@question@box{\textwidth}{\problem #2}%%
  \ae@save@mp\ae@answer@box{\dimexpr\textwidth-2em}{\color{red}#3}%%  
  \noindent
  \usebox\ae@question@box
  \newline
  \begin{minipage}[c][#1]{\textwidth}
    \vspace{-\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\lineskip}
    \if@showanswer@
      \centering
      %%
      \usebox{\ae@answer@box}%%
      \par
    \fi
  \end{minipage}%%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\showanswers
\question[1in]
         {sdlfkj lsdfjk sliewoi m sdfie lkjsdlfkjeio u}
         {this is my answer}

\question[1in]
          {Find the area bounded by the $x$-axis and the curve $y=x^{2}-4$}
          {To find the area evaluate the following integral:
           \[
              \int_{-2}^{2} x^{2}-4\,\mathrm{d}x
           \]
           }

\end{document}
```

Result when `\showanswers` is present:
[image]

and when `\showanswers` is not present:

[image]

Comment: Just so I know: Using your method is it possible to add items like...1) find the area bounded by the x-axis and the curves: (a) y=x (b) y = x^2 (c) y = x^3...?

Comment: @GuilhermeVargas Is that a math question or a LaTeX question?  If it's a LaTeX quesiton, you can write whatever you want in the given parts to the question and answer.

Comment: It's a LaTeX question. I was wondering if "Question 2" in your example could have sub items (a), (b) and so on..

Comment: @GuilhermeVargas Sure you could. You'll have to tweak things a bit: namely, separate out the question and answer parts of my answer.  I don't have time to update my answer right now, but I'll try to get to it later today.

Comment: Alright, @A.Ellett! I will wait for your help once again, I am typing a document that could use that solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a box. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\questionbox}[2][1in]{%
  \item #2\\*
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \fbox{\rule{0pt}{#1}\rule{\linewidth}{0pt}}%
  \endgroup
  \par
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\questionbox{This is a question}

\questionbox[2in]{This is a more difficult question}

\questionbox{This is a question}

\questionbox{This is a question}

\questionbox{This is a question}

\questionbox{This is a question}

\questionbox{This is a question}

\questionbox{This is a question}

\questionbox{This is a question}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A variant where you can specify notes to the question, which are shown only if `\shownotestrue` is active.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifshownotes
\newsavebox{\questionboxbox}
\newenvironment{questionbox}[2][1in]
 {\def\questionboxheight{#1}%
  \item #2\\*
  \begin{lrbox}{\questionboxbox}
  \begin{minipage}[t][#1]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}}
 {\end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \ifshownotes
    \fbox{\usebox\questionboxbox}%
  \else
    \fbox{%
      \parbox[t][\questionboxheight]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{
        \strut\hspace*{\fill}
      }%
    }%
  \fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\begin{questionbox}{This is a question}
Some notes about this question
\end{questionbox}

\begin{questionbox}{This is a more difficult question}
Some notes about this question
Some notes about this question
Some notes about this question
Some notes about this question
Some notes about this question
Some notes about this question
Some notes about this question
Some notes about this question
\end{questionbox}

\begin{questionbox}[.5in]{This is an easy question}
Some notes about this question
\end{questionbox}

\end{enumerate}

\clearpage

\shownotestrue

\begin{enumerate}

\begin{questionbox}{This is a question}
Some notes about this question
\end{questionbox}

\begin{questionbox}{This is a more difficult question}
Some notes about this question
Some notes about this question
Some notes about this question
Some notes about this question
Some notes about this question
Some notes about this question
Some notes about this question
Some notes about this question
\end{questionbox}

\begin{questionbox}[.5in]{This is an easy question}
Some notes about this question
\end{questionbox}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This kinda works. I want to actually type in the answers (or some notes of my choosing) inside those boxes. Is that possible?

Comment: @GuilhermeVargas Is it good now?

Comment: It works fine. I'll save your answer in a .tex file because it can be a great thing to have in hand. I found Ellett's code a little more well-explained from a beginner's point of view, so that's why I chose their answer (I wish I could tag more than just one answer here in situations like this). I upvoted your answer because it's a great alternative. Thank you so much.